# Replace two finds with str_replace

Tags: php

Ok, so I have `$randomImage`, if I were to echo this I would get `"images/image_name.jpg"`. I only want it to echo the image_name. I've managed to hide `"images/"` but how can I do the same with `".jpg"` ?

Here is my code:

```
$imagesDir = 'images/'; 
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); 
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
echo str_replace("images/","","$randomImage");
```

Comment: You can use [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

Comment: `echo pathinfo($randomImage)['basename'];`

Comment: @Steve that outputs to image_name.jpg, I only want it to output to image_name

Answer (score 2):

Try using `pathinfo` with the `PATHINFO_FILENAME` argument on the image path.

```
$imagesDir = 'images/'; 
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); 
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
echo pathinfo($randomImage, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

e.g.

```
var_dump(pathinfo('images/image_name.jpg', PATHINFO_FILENAME));
//string(4) "image_name"
```

Alternatively you could get every part of the file's info.

```
$pinfo = pathinfo('images/image_name.jpg');
var_dump($pinfo);
/*
array(4) {
  ["dirname"]=>
  string(6) "images"
  ["basename"]=>
  string(14) "image_name.jpg"
  ["extension"]=>
  string(3) "jpg"
  ["filename"]=>
  string(10) "image_name"
}
*/
```

Allowing you to use

```
$pinfo['filename']; //image_name
```

Resource: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$replace = array("images/",".jpg");
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); 
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
echo str_replace($replace,"","$randomImage");
```

Answer (score 0):

**str_replace()** can take arrays as arguments for both the search and replace parameters.

Example:

```
$myString = 'this and that are pretty awesome!';
$search = array('this', 'that');
$replace = array('you', 'I');

$myOutput = str_replace($search, $replace, $myString);

echo $myOutput; // you and I are pretty awesome!
```

In your case, you could use:

```
$imageName = str_replace(array('/images/','.jpg'), '', '/images/imageName.jpg');
```